# how to print loading with dots appearing and disappearing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a python script that print loading with dots appearing 1 by 1 and disappering them 1 by 1. I know how to disappear all of them but I want them them to go back 1 by 1.

Here is the code:-

```
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(4):
        dot = "."*y
        loading = (f"Loading {dot}")
        print(loading + "   ", end = '\r')
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the part that outputs dots in your code by making it a function.

```
import time

def dotmove(n):
    dot = "."*n
    loading = (f"Loading {dot}")
    print(loading + "   ", end = '\r')
    time.sleep(1)

for x in range(5):
    for y in range(4):
        dotmove(y)
    for z in range(2,  0, -1):
        dotmove(z)
```

Comment: Thank It worked. Can you give an explanation.

Comment: @CodeWithYash I looked at your code and found that the number of dots goes from 0 to 3 depending on the y value of the for loop. So, using range(), it was implemented by adding -1 from 2 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function that returns a "zigzag" sequence that corresponds to the number of dots you want. The [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#divmod) builtin comes in handy here. (If you remove the  `if` statement from the `zigzag` function, you get the same behavior you had before.)

This function also avoids the need for nested loops, which also makes it easy to print out an infinite loading sequence (since you can just increment a counter).

I'm also using [`.ljust(12)`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) (where 12 is the length of `"Loading "` plus 4, the maximum number of dots) to left-justify the string that's printed on every line to the correct length instead of just "blindly" adding a number of spaces.

```
import time


def zigzag(counter, maximum):
    iteration, step = divmod(counter, maximum)
    if iteration % 2 == 1:  # go backwards every other iteration
        return maximum - step
    return step


for x in range(20):
    n_dots = zigzag(x, 4)  # up to 4 dots
    message = f"Loading {'.' * n_dots}"
    print(message.ljust(12), end='\r')
    time.sleep(.1)
```

This prints out

```
Loading
Loading .
Loading ..
Loading ...
Loading ....
Loading ...
Loading ..
Loading .
Loading
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

A more simplified version

```
import time
def load(dot_lenth=type(int),delay=1):
  dot=""
  for i in range(dot_lenth):
    print(f"Loading{dot}",end="\r")
    dot+="."
    time.sleep(delay)
    
  for i in reversed(range(dot_lenth)):
    print(f"Loading{dot[0:i]} ",end="\r")
    time.sleep(delay)
load(20,0.1)
```